# [ActionScript][ERROR]Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property

Tags: actionscript

I've been working on a Flash Register but I keep getting an error that says `Line 170 and Line 174 Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property.`

Here are the functions

```
 function nextView()
 {
   this.__set__currentViewIndex(++this.__get__currentViewIndex()); //Line 170
 } 
 function prevView()
{
   this.__set__currentViewIndex(--this.__get__currentViewIndex()); //Line 174
}
```

Comment: ++this.__get__currentViewIndex() is basically the same as saying `this.__get__currentViewIndex()  = this.__get__currentViewIndex()  + 1` so it's trying to assign the value to a function, which just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I fixed it. `this.__set__currentViewIndex(this.__get__currentViewIndex()+ 1);` was the fix